# Deleteing characters from end of a file in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, file, file-writing

I am using `fs` module's `appendFile()` function to append JSON data to a file.

After appending I need to delete the last character from the file and append a new character. I tried to use `\b` escape sequence to delete the last character but it did'nt work.

Besides it would be very helpful to know how to edit characters in the middle of the file.

Comment: You don't 'edit' characters in the middle of the file.  You can use the `position` argument for `fs.write()` to write any number of bytes to that file at that position (if the file is opened in an appropriate mode).  You can also shorten the length of the file with `fs.truncate(...)`.

Comment: Though if you're appending data to a file, why don't you fix the data BEFORE you append it to the file and then you don't have to fix the file after the fact?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this;
Replace the closing the brace ']' of the JSON inside the file with 'comma' using

```
var fd = fs.openSync("file.txt", "r+");
var currentDataLength = data.length;
var buf = new Buffer(","); // create a buffer
  if(currentDataLength > 2) {
    fs.writeSync(fd, buf, 0, buf.length, currentDataLength-1); // this replaces '[' with ',' to separate the objects in the JSON
}

var inputData = `${JSON.stringify({testData: 'Dare Something'})}]`; //  notice that array closing brace ']' is included
currentDataLength += inputData.length; //update the variable holding the JSON Data length of you file

fs.writeFileSync('file.txt', inputData, {encoding: 'utf8', flag: 'a+'}); //updates file
```